# ActiveRecord: how to select a single column from join query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`user` has_many `devices`.

EDIT: `device` has a `registration_id` field

I want to get an array of all `registration_id` of devices of users followed by a certain user.

I'm trying:

```
@user.followers.join(:devices).select("devices.registration_id")
```

but that seem to work,
how can I do this query ?

Comment: How about `Device.find_all_by_user_id(@user.follower_ids)` ? You get the whole Device models, but does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but think this should work:

```
@user.followers.map { |f| f.devices.pluck(:registration_id) }.flatten
```

**upd**: To minimize queries count I can offer this solution:

```
Device.where(user_id: @user.followers.pluck(:id)).pluck(:registration_id)
```

Comment: it returns the required result, but it queries the devices table for each user id, so for n users there are n queries.  is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     try by swapping
        @user.select("devices.registration_id").followers.join(:devices)
```

Comment: NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<User:0x00000004fa3440>

Answer (score 0):

You might want to recheck ur association between Device and Registration

```
Device
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :registration  #but in this case the device_id should be in Registration
```

Considering registration_id is a field of Device

```
 arr = @user.followers.collect(&:id)
 @user.devices.collect{|d| d.registration_id if arr.include?d.follower_id}
```

Comment: Care to add some comments to your code? Maybe it works, but commenting it will be helpful for others looking for same issue

Comment: i wanted to say that the association is wrong. If Device has_one :registration then device_id should be in registration

Comment: `@user.devices.collect(&:registration_id)` returns the registration ids of all devices of @user, I want to get the registration ids of all devices of `@user.followers`

Comment: can u post the models and their associations here?

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.followers.join(:devices).select("devices.registration_id")
```

Should work if you put en extra s after .join. It is called .joins("devices")